# Extracting certain numbers from a cell containing numbers and special characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cells that contain both numbers and special characters such as this:

```
[1:250:10]
```

The 'coordinates' shown above can be in the following format.

`[(1-9):(1-499):(1-15)]` in terms of what numbers can be within each part.

How do I extract these three numbers into three separate cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `Cell A1` the to extract first number use following formula

```
=MID(A1,2,(FIND(":",A1,1)-2))
```

for second number use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(":" & A1&REPT(" ",6),":",REPT(":",255)),2*255,255),":","")
```

finally for third number enter

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),"]","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to clarify that the [ ] are part of the paste

Comment: I just to get it so the [ and the ] are excluded too. Currently it works but shows [1 in B1, and 10] in D1 because of the [ ]

Comment: @FrederickAyres Then why don't you try to modify this answer to deal with the `[]`

Comment: @FrederickAyres - Overlooked those `[]`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just tossing out some other options.

First number since it only has a length of 1 digit and is on the left side, use the following:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,2))
```

second number will be found by locating the : in the string

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)-(FIND(":",A1)+1))
```

third number will be dealt with in the same way as the second but we will use the second : and the ] as the identifiers as to where to grab from and how much to pull.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-(FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)+1))
```

now all those number will actually come through as text.  If you want to have them as numbers in the cells, send them through a math operation that will not change their value.  Do something like +0, -0, or *1 at the end.  Alternatively you could add -- at the start of each formula (yes that is double - incase you were wondering if it was a typo)